# Angular2 - ts files don't live-recompile with npm start

Tags: angular, npm

i've created a new angular 2 project with `ng new test`.
When i execute `npm start` or `ng serve` i can see that if i change an html file, the browser page refreshes correctly.

But if i change a ts file nothing happens. 
In browser's console i see:

```
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling... (two times)

[WDS] Nothing changed.
```

In server console i see that it recompiles but with old sources. For example if i have an error that i correct, after saving the file i still see the same error.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4338
I installed webpack 1.2.4 and it works now!